# Picking, translating, rotating objects. How do I do this?

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, tao-framework

**Introduction**

I am currently using the TAO framework to draw graphics in OpenGL.  Listed below is my code for drawing boxes of any size using textures or colors, whatever the user specifies. This works perfectly fine at drawing as shown below as well.

The project is written in VB .NET 2010 but since most of it was written with the help of C# I am posting it under both languages since the answer could be in C# and then translated to VB .NET.

**Problem**

Now the next part that I am trying to develop is the ability to select an object and rotate / translate it. I don't have a clue how to do this. I have looked online and have only found examples in C# which are fine but most methods don't produce the correct result. I do know that I need to name my objects which I believe I have done. So my question is how can this be done?

I could also be completely off with my existing code that draws everything. I am not sure.

**Existing Program**

[image]

**CODE**

Here is my initial load function:

```
Private Sub DrawInit()
    Gl.glClearColor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F)
    Gl.glShadeModel(Gl.GL_SMOOTH)
    Gl.glClearDepth(1.0#)
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    Gl.glDepthFunc(Gl.GL_LESS)
    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_STENCIL_TEST)
    Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, Gl.GL_NICEST)

    Draw_Shapes()

End Sub
```

My draw shapes function

```
 Private Sub Draw_Shapes()
    draw_boxes()
End Sub
```

My draw_box function

```
Private Sub draw_boxes()



    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim startx As Integer = 0
    Dim starty As Integer = 0
    Dim startz As Integer = 0

    Dim deltax As Integer = 0
    Dim deltay As Integer = 0
    Dim deltaz As Integer = 0

    Dim front_face_color As Color
    Dim back_face_color As Color
    Dim top_face_color As Color
    Dim bottom_face_color As Color
    Dim left_face_color As Color
    Dim right_face_color As Color

    Dim front_face_texture As Bitmap
    Dim back_face_texture As Bitmap
    Dim top_face_texture As Bitmap
    Dim bottom_face_texture As Bitmap
    Dim left_face_texture As Bitmap
    Dim right_face_texture As Bitmap

    Dim front_face_num_textures As Point
    Dim back_face_num_textures As Point
    Dim top_face_num_textures As Point
    Dim bottom_face_num_textures As Point
    Dim left_face_num_textures As Point
    Dim right_face_num_textures As Point

    Dim front_texture As Boolean
    Dim back_texture As Boolean
    Dim top_texture As Boolean
    Dim bottom_texture As Boolean
    Dim left_texture As Boolean
    Dim right_texture As Boolean


    Do Until i = boxes.Length - 1
        startx = boxes(i).start_x
        starty = boxes(i).start_y
        startz = boxes(i).start_z
        deltax = boxes(i).delta_x
        deltay = boxes(i).delta_y
        deltaz = boxes(i).delta_z
        front_face_color = boxes(i).front_face_color
        back_face_color = boxes(i).back_face_color
        top_face_color = boxes(i).top_face_color
        bottom_face_color = boxes(i).bottom_face_color
        left_face_color = boxes(i).left_face_color
        right_face_color = boxes(i).right_face_color


        front_face_texture = boxes(i).front_face_texture
        back_face_texture = boxes(i).back_face_texture
        top_face_texture = boxes(i).top_face_texture
        bottom_face_texture = boxes(i).bottom_face_texture
        left_face_texture = boxes(i).left_face_texture
        right_face_texture = boxes(i).right_face_texture

        front_face_num_textures = boxes(i).front_face_num_textures
        back_face_num_textures = boxes(i).back_face_num_textures
        top_face_num_textures = boxes(i).top_face_num_textures
        bottom_face_num_textures = boxes(i).bottom_face_num_textures
        left_face_num_textures = boxes(i).left_face_num_textures
        right_face_num_textures = boxes(i).right_face_num_textures


        If front_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            front_texture = False
        Else
            front_texture = True
        End If

        If back_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            back_texture = False
        Else
            back_texture = True
        End If

        If top_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            top_texture = False
        Else
            top_texture = True
        End If

        If bottom_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            bottom_texture = False
        Else
            bottom_texture = True
        End If

        If left_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            left_texture = False
        Else
            left_texture = True
        End If

        If right_face_texture Is Nothing Then
            right_texture = False
        Else
            right_texture = True
        End If

        Gl.glLoadName(num_shapes)
        Gl.glNewList(i + 1, Gl.GL_COMPILE)



        draw_rectangular_face(front_texture, front_face_color, front_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), front_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(back_texture, back_face_color, back_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), back_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(top_texture, top_face_color, top_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), top_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(bottom_texture, bottom_face_color, bottom_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), bottom_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(left_texture, left_face_color, left_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), left_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(right_texture, right_face_color, right_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), right_face_num_textures)


        Gl.glEndList()

        num_shapes = num_shapes + 1

        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

My draw face function

```
Private Sub draw_rectangular_face(ByVal texture As Boolean, ByVal face_color As Color, ByVal texture_image As Bitmap, ByVal point1 As ThreeDPoint, ByVal point2 As ThreeDPoint, ByVal point3 As ThreeDPoint, ByVal point4 As ThreeDPoint, ByVal num_textures As Point)

    If texture = True Then
        load_textures(texture_image)
    End If


    Gl.glBindTexture(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1)

    If texture = True Then
        Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D) 'turn on for texture
    Else
        Gl.glDisable(Gl.GL_TEXTURE_2D) 'turn on for color
    End If


    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS)

    If texture = True Then
        Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1) 'turn on for texture
    Else
        Gl.glColor3f(face_color.R / 256, face_color.G / 256, face_color.B / 256) 'turn on for color
    End If


    Gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0) : Gl.glVertex3f(point1.x, point1.y, point1.z)
    Gl.glTexCoord2f(num_textures.X, 0) : Gl.glVertex3f(point2.x, point2.y, point2.z)
    Gl.glTexCoord2f(num_textures.X, num_textures.Y) : Gl.glVertex3f(point3.x, point3.y, point3.z)
    Gl.glTexCoord2f(0, num_textures.Y) : Gl.glVertex3f(point4.x, point4.y, point4.z)

    Gl.glEnd()
End Sub
```

My DrawScene event which is used to translate and rotate the world:

```
Private Sub DrawScene()

    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT Or Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT Or Gl.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT)
    Gl.glLoadIdentity()
    'move reference?
    Gl.glTranslatef(camera_xloc, camera_yloc, camera_zloc)
    ' Gl.glTranslatef(0.0F, 0.0F, -20.0F)


    'rotate
    Gl.glRotatef(camera_xrot, 1, 0, 0)
    Gl.glRotatef(camera_yrot, 0, 1, 0)
    Gl.glRotatef(camera_zrot, 0, 0, 1)

    Dim i As Integer = 1
    Do Until i > num_shapes
        Gl.glCallList(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Gl.glFlush()
    Application.DoEvents()
    Gdi.SwapBuffers(hDC)



    If intialload = 0 Then
        intialload = 1
        RaiseEvent initial_load_completed()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have tried doing the following to translate shape # 1 to 1000,1000,1000 with no success:

```
Gl.glLoadName(num_shapes)
        Gl.glNewList(i + 1, Gl.GL_COMPILE)



        If num_shapes = 1 Then
            Gl.glPushMatrix()
            Gl.glTranslatef(1000, 1000, 1000)
        End If


        draw_rectangular_face(front_texture, front_face_color, front_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), front_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(back_texture, back_face_color, back_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), back_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(top_texture, top_face_color, top_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), top_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(bottom_texture, bottom_face_color, bottom_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), bottom_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(left_texture, left_face_color, left_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx + deltax, starty, startz + deltaz), left_face_num_textures)

        draw_rectangular_face(right_texture, right_face_color, right_face_texture, New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty + deltay, startz + deltaz), New ThreeDPoint(startx, starty, startz + deltaz), right_face_num_textures)

        If num_shapes = 1 Then
            Gl.glPopMatrix()
        End If



        Gl.glEndList()
```

Comment: The question is a bit broad to fully answer. Picking, rotating and translating are three different tasks that need different approaches. To pick an object you shoot a ray through the cursor and see what objects are hit. Translating can be done by projecting the objects on a plane and rotations can be handled by various trackball implementations. I would advice you to formulate a new question for a specific problem. Please also show, what you tried so far. Picking is a very common task.

Comment: As for selecting and "shooting a ray through the object", how do I establish a list of objects with their existing coordinates then?

Comment: You should have them somewhere in your memory. How else could you even draw the objects? `boxes` seems a good starting point.

Comment: I added my "DrawScene" sub which I used to rotate and translate the world. I wasn't aware that I had to store the objects' information to a list outside of the tao framework but I can do that. My next question is how to then translate just one object instead of all of them like I do in my DrawScene?

Comment: I also updated with what I have tried in terms of translating.

Comment: Implementing picking is a tough task if you don't even know how to transform objects separately. See `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()`. Anyway, please ask a fresh question about a concrete problem.